# Freeze top Row and First Column in Gridview C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is it possible to freeze the Top row and  First column in Gridview both at the same time? and allow left to right scroll and top to bottom scroll?

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible as it is - out of the box.

The `GridView` is rendered as `Table`. So any javascript library that handles and render table may do what you search for.

One that I can suggest is the [jQuery DataTable](https://datatables.net/) and this is how you simple convert the GridView to this one.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
```